# Bind report parameter to a sql output jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have an existing report which needs to modified a little. Suppose my report query is like

```
select name,currency,productcode from  where name=?
```

Now this '?' value will come from a report parameter say countryName. That can be done using parameterized query not a problem.
Now what I need is this parameter countryName to get the data from another query like below

```
select name from countries
```

In short I want to bind the value of report parameter countryName to the output of the above query and also I want to put this query in report it self.
Using birt its very easy but I want to know is it possible with jasper?

P.S I'm novice in jasper report.

I have tried to give an small scenario to represent my issue. The actual report is much more that this and is very complex.
Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: [Parameterized Queries](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query)

Comment: For parameterized query to work, you will execute the select name from countries in java, pass the name as a parameter (in the hashmap) and then execute the other query in jasper report... in stead of ? you will have your parameter name $P{TheParam}

Comment: @AlexK parameterized query I can run that's not a problem. The problem is how do I bind the report parameter countryName with another sql's output

Comment: You need to gives us some code (jrxml and java) if you are having a specific issue, something that is not working. Like this the question is likely to be closed (recommend to find a tutorial)

Comment: @PetterFriberg in the organization we have report engine module which executes the report and for this particular issue I'm not sure I can change it. So I'm looking for some solution which can be solved by the report itself (if possible)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I want the dataset to be shown only for one country. I have modified my question a little and tried to explain better.

Comment: Seems that you like an interface that shows you the countries, then you clic a country and show selected data?.... are you using jasper report server, how are you calling the reports... How decide which is the country to be displayed?

Comment: @PetterFriberg you are very much right we need an interface(combobox) using which we select the country and that country will passed as report parameter. We have a custom report module which uses jasperreports-3.7.2. Now using birt its very easy you just map the report parameter value to query result.

Comment: So whats the the problem with @Alex K comment?, just pass the combobo value in the Map to jasper report map.put("c",combobo.value()); and in jasper report select name,currency,productcode from  where name=$P{c}??, it is very easy in jasper report aswell... (you need to define the parameter also)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Need some solution which can be handled from the report is self instead of modifying the standard module. If no other option then probably will have to consider it.

Comment: In the report some way we need to know which country to display... if you have it in the combobox in some way you need to pass it.... and the easiest way is through parameter...   if you had a static method in your combo interface also this could be called....

Answer (score 0):

I give you an answer how this can be achieved without passing **anything** through the parameter map (even if I think the parameter map should be the preferred way, modify your standard module to support parameter map)

You say you will have combobox value with the country name, we need to make it static. (or have a static way to access it, "there can be only one")

Example class of your **interface**:

```
package com.your.package;

public class SelectCountryInterface {

  private static JComboBox<String> selectCountry;

  public static synchronized String getSelectedCountry(){
    Object value = selectCountry.getSelectedItem();
    if (value instanceof String){
        return (String)value;
    }
    return "";
  }

  //...Here goes you code to instance and populate the combobox
}
```

In **jasper report** (.jrxml)

1. Define a parameter and set the `defaultValueExpression` to point at your static method in class, this way it will be initialized with the value that you are providing from your interface class.

   ```
   <parameter name="country" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
     <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[com.your.package.SelectCountryInterface.getSelectedCountry()]]> </defaultValueExpression>
   </parameter>
   ```
2. Set the `queryString` to use your parameter

   ```
   <queryString>
      <![CDATA[select name,currency,productcode from  where name=$P{country}]]>
   </queryString>
   ```